# Accessing JavaScript Object Through an HTTP GET Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to access a JavaScript object through an HTTP GET response in Node.js.
For instance, accessing the jQuery object of a webpage that imports the jQuery library.

The Webpage http://example.com:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js">
...
</head>
<body>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

Node.js HTTP GET request:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get("http://example.com", function(res) {
  //Is jQuery object accessible through res object ?
  var body = '';

  res.on('data', function(data){
    body += data;
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(body)
  });
})

.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Error: " + e.message);
});
```

How can I access the jQuery object through the HTTP GET response ?

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: You'd have to make the request with something that actually runs and interprets the remote JavaScript. At the moment, the remote Javascript is just a series of random characters, nothing more.

Comment: @Pekka웃 How can I manage to do that ? PhantomJS would be helpful for that ?

Comment: Yup, that looks like exactly the thing you'd need

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you! Can you please explain what do you mean by "series of random characters" ? What the response object actually contains ? The <script> tag only ?

Comment: I just meant as long as you're just using `http.get`, there is no jQuery object to access - just the response body.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the jQuery object through the HTTP GET response ?

There is no jQuery object.  When you fetch a web page, you are just getting the raw HTML.  There's no parsing of the page.  There's no running of scripts in the page.  You just fetched the RAW HTML of the page.  It's a block of text.

If you wanted to parse the page, run the scripts, etc... you'd have to use a DOM loader (something that simulates much of a browser environment).  A common tool used in node.js to parse the HTML and give you a pseudo-DOM that you can then query is the [Cheerio library](https://cheerio.js.org/) which gives you a subset of jQuery like functionality to operate on a pseudo DOM.